# unordered values in a column assingned based on a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df1:

```
   xx  yy  zz
A  5   3   12
B  3   3   2
C  6   6   6
```

And a dictionary1:

```
{'A':'i','C':'jj',B:'kk'}
```

I would like to create a new df column with the corresponding values associated with the keys that appear in the index.

this is my code:

```
list1=[]
for k, v in dictionary1.items():
    if k in list(df1.index):
        list1.append(dictionary1[k])

df1['oo']=list1
```

The issue is that the values assigned in the column are unordered.
The desired output is:

```
   xx  yy  zz   oo
A  5   3   12   i
B  3   3   2    kk
C  6   6   6    jj
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) for mapping by dictionary:

```
dictionary1 = {'A':'i','C':'jj','B':'kk'}
df1['oo'] = df1.index.map(dictionary1)
print (df1)
  xx  yy  zz  oo
A   5   3  12   i
B   3   3   2  kk
C   6   6   6  jj
```

For oldier pandas versions add `.get`:

```
df1['oo'] = df1.index.map(dictionary1.get)
```